# what is the reason for fopen's failure to open a file

Tags: c++, fopen

I have the following code where I am trying to open a text file.

```
char frd[32]="word-list.txt";
   FILE *rd=fopen(frd,"rb");
   if(!rd)
       std::cout<<"Coudn't open file\t"<<frd;
```

I am using vc 2010 and the file is in the debug directory of this project.
Can anyone tell me why it is not able to open the file?

Comment: What do the docs say about Copenhagen failure types?  There should be some way to find out.

Comment: Does the file exist (in the execution path)?

Comment: Check the file and/or containing directory's permissions.

Comment: Using `std::cout` means you're not writing pure C (that's C++).  You should probably be using `std::cerr`.  The most likely cause of trouble seems to me to be that the current directory is not the debug directory of your project - so the file isn't in the current directory.  The error number should confirm that the file does not exist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
errno = 0;
FILE *fb = fopen("/home/jeegar/filename","r");
if(fb==NULL)
    printf("its null");
else
    printf("working");


printf("Error %d \n", errno);


}
```

this way if fopen gets fail then it will set error number you can find those error number list at here  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html

Comment: the problem was not in opening the file. 'if(rd)' was evaluated to true and so the message line was executed. i should have used 'if(rd=NULL)'

Comment: if fopen() gets fail then it will return NULL so rd will be NULL now in your code you have written if(!rd) [not if(rd)] means it will be executed when rd will be NULL, if file open succesfully then that message will never prints.. and if you want to use == then you shoud write if(rd==NULL) noy if(rd=NULL)

Comment: please always take care for what you are typing in your code and also on SO

Answer (score 2):

Look at the errno variable which is set in the event of an error. It's a global variable. It's been a while, but probably include errno.h which will give you the definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `man fopen` - it says `Upon successful completion fopen() return a FILE pointer. Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error`.

Please check whether the file exists in the execution path or in your program, check the `errno`

Answer (score 0):

`r Open for reading (existing file only) and
rb  Open for reading (existing file only) in binary mode`. Make sure you have the file in your working directory.

Comment: i am 100% certain(as far as I know) I have the file in the working directory. Plus I have tried to open it without the binary mode and the result is the same.